# why pattern "/***" can not match "/api/login" using Spring's AntPathMatcher?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        AntPathMatcher matcher = new AntPathMatcher();
        System.out.println(matcher.match("/**", "/api/login")); //true  //1
        System.out.println(matcher.match("/***", "/api/login"));//false //2
}
```

Belowing is the javadoc of AntPathMatcher:

The mapping matches URLs using the following rules:

- '?' matches one character
- '*' matches zero or more characters
- '**' matches zero or more directories in a path

I am confused why line 2 return false?

'***' is not equals to '**' + '*' ?

Comment: Because the wildcards are `?`, `*` and `**`. `***` is **not** a valid wildcard and **matches only** `***`

Answer (score 1):

As you have already noted:

- '?' matches one character
- '*' matches zero or more characters
- '**' matches zero or more directories in a path

'***' is not in this list and is therefore not a wildcard.

It matches only the path '***'.